# Install Ubuntu 16.04 on XPS 13 with dual boot cannot shrink NTFS

Tags: dual-boot

Hi I'm trying to shrink NTFS in windows to make about 400gb for Ubuntu and 100gb for windows but diskpart even in admin mode nor risk management will let me. What is the work around?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally recommended to use Windows tools to resize or move NTFS partitions, even though Ubuntu has been able to reliable read and write to NTFS for several years.

That means you'll need to use Windows Disk Manager or similar tool to shrink the partition, though once that's done, you can use Ubuntu tools to create the new partitions (preferably `ext4`), or let the Ubuntu installer do so (select the "install in free space" option).

Very important -- there needs to be 400 GB of free space in the partition in order to shrink it by 400 GB -- are you certain that's true?